# ST_Buffer distance units

Tags: postgis

Hello I used the ST_Buffer to set a 5 kilometre buffer with this code:

```html
CREATE TABLE Buf_5km_Schiff as
SELECT ST_Buffer(geom, 0.05) 
FROM public."Input_Schifffahrtswege";
```

It works but im not sure why I need to set 0.05 for 5 kilometres. I tried 5 and 5000 at first but it did not work.

Btw. I used the EPSG 4258 Coordinate System.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EPSG:4258](https://epsg.io/4258) is in degrees. You will have to transform to some metric projection to use the buffer setting you are expecting. You could try [EPSG:3857](https://epsg.io/3857) by wrapping your geometry column into `ST_Transform(geom, 3857)` and then calling `ST_Buffer` but note that 3857 will give you a approximation but there will be more suitable projections to improve the result.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I do the exact same thing in a GIS (ArcGIS Pro) with the EPSG 4258 layer and a buffer with 5 kilometres the output is still in the 4258 coordinate system, so I wonder if the Arc GIS workflow is not correct then, because if what you say is true, the buffer tool should reproject it right?, but this is not the case, this is very confusing to me.

Comment: I am not sure how ArcGIS works but if the form field is "km" I guess they transform it under the hood and re-transform it again after buffering.

Comment: Okay thank you, I read now, that another possibility is to cast it from a geometry to a geography (geom: :geography) I don't know what this means, but it works too.

Comment: Yes, that will also work, you can read more about it here https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/postgis-and-the-geography-type or here https://medium.com/coord/postgis-performance-showdown-geometry-vs-geography-ec99967da4f0